# Show that: $\frac{(a_1+.....+a_n)^{2n}}{a_1^n+\cdots+a_n^n} \ge n^{n-1}a_1a_2 \cdots a_n$

Tags: inequality

Let $a_1, a_2,...,a_n >0$ then show that:
$$\frac{(a_1+.....+a_n)^{2n}}{a_1^n+\cdots+a_n^n} \ge n^{n-1}a_1a_2 \cdots a_n$$

Equality holds if only if $a_1=a_2=\cdots=a_n$

[See also](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means)

Comment: Have you tried this for $n=2$?  What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: for what stands $n$ here?

Comment: Yes, I tried with n=2 the inequality is true, n=3 I calculator it is true

Comment: where he stuck is clear, he stuck with the case $n$

Comment: @Oai Thanh Đào if you say that the equality occurs for $a_1=...=a_n$ so you must change $n^{n-1}$ on $n^{2n-1}$ and we get a wrong inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint.

After using the Vasc's Equal Variable Method it's enough to prove that
$$\left(x+n-1\right)^{2n}\geq n^{n-1}x\left(x^n+n-1\right)$$
for positive $x$, which is your homework.